# Is $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[x] $ a Principal Ideal Domain (PID)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let
$$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}:=\left\{\frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}, p\nmid b\right\}$$

Is $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[x] $ a Principal Ideal Domain (PID)? Use the following theorem:

Let $ f,q\in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[x] $ $$\deg(fq)=\deg(f)+\deg(q)$$

---

My idea to prove $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[x]$ is a PID is prove $\mathbb{Z
}_{(p)}$ is a field then it is a PID but I wouldn't be using the previous theorem

Can you help me please?

Comment: $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ is not a field (find an element which is not invertible). Maybe you know that $\Bbb Z[x]$ is not a PID. Can you transfer the argument to this case?

Comment: @leoli1 Thank you I just read some proofs of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a PID but I don't know hoy transfer the arguments to this case using the theorem of degrees

Comment: In general the idea is to take a non-zero element $s$ which is not a unit and to look at the ideal $I=(s,x)$. If this where generated by only one element this would need to have degree $0$ (by your degree theorem) since $s\in I$. So $I$ is actually generated by an element in the ring $R$. But this element cannot be a unit since otherwise $I=R[x]$ but if it not a unit can we still have $x\in I$? This is more or less the argument in the answer by Sabino. (Here I assumed $R$ just to be an integral domain but not a field)

Comment: @leoli1 thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the ideal $(p,x)$.

This ideal is not whole the ring after localization because does not intersect the set of elements you are inverting.

Moreover, it is not generated by only one element: let suppose that there exists a dipendence relation between $x$ and $p$, you can lift this relation to a dipendence relation in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, which is absurd because of the $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-analogue of the relation between degrees that you stated in the question.

Comment: Thank you so much! just one question why the ideal $(p,x)$ does not intersect the set of elements that I am inverting?

Comment: You are inverting elements that are not multiples of $p.$